# Como deletar um commit já feito no bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

Gostaria de saber como deletar um commit já feito no bitbucket, eu já fiz o push mas somente olhando no repositório encontrei um erro como faço para remover essa alteração?

Comment: Bruno, o git reset não te atende: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset ?

Comment: @DanielMendes então eu até tentei essa opção ele até remove do repositório local mas ainda consta no Bitbucket.

Comment: Também rola fazer um git revert: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert.html. Esse cara reverter as alterações do commit informado, depois você faz novamente um push desse revert, isso não vai apagar o commit, mas vai "desfazer" ele.

Comment: @DanielMendes tentar isso